# Why hibernate 6 throw an excetion "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Already registered a copy: SqmBasicValuedSimplePath" when adding a predicate?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.TypedQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Expression;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Order;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Root;

import com.abned.forms.GetAllForm;
import com.abned.forms.PaginationForm;
import com.abned.SortingForm;
import com.abned.forms.SortingForm.SortingDirection;

public abstract class GetAllService<T> {
    private final EntityManager em;
    public GetAllService(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public GetAllResponse<T> getAll(GetAllForm form) {
        final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(getEntityClass());
        final Root<T> query = buildRootQuery(cq);
        final List<Predicate> predicates = buildPredicates(cb, query, form);

        if (!predicates.isEmpty()) {
            cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        }
        cq.distinct(true);
        cq.orderBy(buildOrderBy(cb, query, form));
        
        final TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = em.createQuery(cq);
        buildPagination(form.getPagination(), typedQuery);
        addAdditionalBuiltins(form, typedQuery);
    
        final List<T> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
        return new GetAllResponse<T>(results, nbTotal(predicates));
    }

    protected Root<T> buildRootQuery(CriteriaQuery<T> cq) {
        return cq.from(getEntityClass());
    }

    protected Long nbTotal(final List<Predicate> predicates) {
        final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        final Root<T> query = countQuery.from(getEntityClass());
        if (!predicates.isEmpty()) {
            countQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        }
        final List<Long> totals = em.createQuery(countQuery.select(cb.countDistinct(query))).getResultList();
        if (!totals.isEmpty()) {
            return totals.get(0);
        }
        return 0L;
    }

    protected void buildPagination(PaginationForm pagination, TypedQuery<T> typedQuery) {
        if (pagination == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (null != pagination.getLimit() && pagination.getLimit() > 0) {
            if (null != pagination.getPage() && pagination.getPage() > 0) {
                typedQuery.setFirstResult((pagination.getPage().intValue() - 1) * pagination.getLimit());
            }
            typedQuery.setMaxResults(pagination.getLimit());
        }
    }

    protected void addAdditionalBuiltins(GetAllForm form, TypedQuery<T> typedQuery) {}

    protected abstract List<Predicate> buildPredicates(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<T> query, GetAllForm form);
    protected abstract Class<T> getEntityClass();

    protected Order[] buildOrderBy(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<T> query, GetAllForm form) {
        final List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        final SortingForm orderBy = form.getSorting();
        if (orderBy != null) {
            final Expression<? extends Serializable> order = getOrderByExpression(query, orderBy);
            if (orderBy.getDir() == null || orderBy.getDir() == SortingDirection.ASC) {
                orders.add(cb.asc(order));
            } else {
                orders.add(cb.desc(order));
            }
        }
        return orders.toArray(new Order[orders.size()]);
    }

    protected Expression<? extends Serializable> getOrderByExpression(Root<T> query, SortingForm orderBy) {
        return query.get(orderBy.getColumn());
    }
}
```

And the concrete class that extends it:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.abned.entities.ExtractionTable;
import com.abned.forms.GetAllExtractionTableForm;
import com.abned.forms.GetAllForm;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import jakarta.persistence.criteria.Root;

@Service
public class GetAllExtractionTable extends GetAllService<ExtractionTable> {
    public GetAllExtractionTable(EntityManager em) {
        super(em);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Predicate> buildPredicates(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<ExtractionTable> query, GetAllForm form) {
        final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (form instanceof GetAllExtractionTableForm) {
            final GetAllExtractionTableForm criteria = (GetAllExtractionTableForm) form;
            if (null != criteria.getOnglet()) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(query.get("onglet"), criteria.getOnglet()));
            }
            if (null != criteria.getType()) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(query.get("type"), criteria.getType()));
            }
            if (null != criteria.getIds() && !criteria.getIds().isEmpty()) {
                predicates.add(query.get("id").in(criteria.getIds()));
            }
        }
        return predicates;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<ExtractionTable> getEntityClass() {
        return ExtractionTable.class;
    }
}
```

So, why nbTotal function throw an exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Already registered a copy: SqmBasicValuedSimplePath(com.louis.scrapping.api.entities.ExtractionTable(6762665638604).onglet)** ?

With hibernate 5.6 (Spring boot 2.7), no exception was thrown.

**Edit: 20 Mey 2023 - my solution**

As @ChristianBeikov explain in comment, with hibernate 6, we can't reuse the built predicates from a query to another query.

So, my solution is to rebuild the predicate by using the new query for nbTotal method. nbTotal function is now like this:

```java
protected Long nbTotal(GetAllForm form) {
        final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        final Root<T> query = countQuery.from(getEntityClass());
        final List<Predicate> predicates = buildPredicates(cb, query, form);
        if (!predicates.isEmpty()) {
            countQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        }
        final List<Long> totals = em.createQuery(countQuery.select(cb.countDistinct(query))).getResultList();
        if (!totals.isEmpty()) {
            return totals.get(0);
        }
        return 0L;
    }
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Obviously, the Hibernate team got it very wrong this time, effectively blocking usage of Spring Boot 3 with Hibernate criteria API.

Comment: It's a bug. We're working on it. Maybe give Hibernate 6.2.0.CR2 a spin?

Comment: Hi @ChristianBeikov. I give it a try with 6.2.0.CR2 as suggested. I got a different error, but related to the same root case. Now it says: "org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreeCreationException: Could not locate TableGroup - ro.work.model.entities.User(229498723922875)" at BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:3398. When debugging, the same property seems to be causing the issue: "SqmBasicValuedSimplePath(ro.work.model.entities.User(229498723922875).activationStatus)".  The root cause seems to be related by this piece of code: countQuery.where(criteria.getRestriction()); - reusing the restriction is not OK.

Comment: I think this bug is relevant to this question: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15951. Hopefully it will be fixed soon. I did not understand the workaround proposed by Jana at 2 January 2023 at 15:18.

Comment: So you are using a `Path` in query Q2, that refers to a `From`/`Root` which was created for a query Q1. That's just not going to work. The only bug here IMO is that we don't report a better error. You will simply have to create a new `From`/`Root` for Q2.

Comment: Hi @ChristianBeikov. I already tried as you suggested, with no success. I have declared a new set of variables for root, criteria query, re-composed the predicates, etc, but the error stays the same.  The only thing the count query and the main query had in common was the same entity manager instance. Could this be the issue?

Comment: The code you showed below in your answer uses the restriction of a different query, which in turn refers to different `From`/`Path` objects than the ones you created for the count query. You have to rebuild the predicates as well for the new query you are creating. If you think you are hitting a bug, please create a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) and share that.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov all the arguments of the count() method from below are declared in new variables and passed as an argument. Initially, they were reused, like you said, but with Hibernate 6 the below method does not work even when arguments are freshly instantiated, specifically for the count query. It may or may not be a bug (it smells like a bug - see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15951 also), but at least a workaround would be nice. Or a full example of a query + count query implementation that actually works on Hibernate 6.

Comment: If you can provide a test case to reproduce this issue, we can look into it.

Comment: Hi @ChristianBeikov, please see my answer with a full code example. Thanks in advance for looking into it.

Comment: The problem is your `countQuery.where(criteria.getRestriction())`. That predicate refers to `From` nodes of the original query, which are not defined in the count query. You have to rebuild your filter predicate for the count query for this to work. Note that you can use `countQuery.where(((SqmPredicate) criteria.getRestriction()).copy(context))` for this purpose. You just need to register the copies for the `From` nodes.

Comment: Hi @ChristianBeikov. I have tried to use: `countQuery.where(((SqmPredicate) criteria.getRestriction()).copy(SqmCopyContext.simpleContext()));` instead of `countQuery.where(criteria.getRestriction());` in JpaUtil, when doing the count, but I got this error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Already registered a copy: SqmSingularJoin(com.work.maintenance.model.entities.Equipment(441362109276458).client(441362109315375) : client)
 at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.SqmCopyContext$1.registerCopy(SqmCopyContext.java:33)

Comment: Like I wrote before, you need to register the copies for the `From` nodes in the `SqmCopyContext`

Comment: @ChristianBeikov can you please write few lines of code as an exemplification of what it needs to be done?

Comment: @ChristianBeikov i posted below my findings after applying your changes to the count class. Unfortunately, that still doesn't fix the issue. Do you have any other suggestion I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need something like this instead:

```java
public class JpaUtil {

    public static <E, D> long count(final EntityManager entityManager,
                                    final CriteriaBuilder cb,
                                    final CriteriaQuery<D> criteria,
                                    final Root<E> root) {
        CriteriaQuery<Long> query = createCountQuery(cb, criteria, root, root.getModel().getJavaType());
        return entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
    }

    private static <T, D> CriteriaQuery<Long> createCountQuery(final CriteriaBuilder cb,
                                                               final CriteriaQuery<D> criteria,
                                                               final Root<T> root,
                                                               final Class<T> entityClass) {

        final CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        final SqmCopyContext copyContext = SqmCopyContext.simpleContext();
        final Root<T> countRoot = countQuery.from(entityClass);
        copyContext.registerCopy(root, countRoot);

        doJoins(root.getJoins(), countRoot, copyContext);
        doJoinsOnFetches(root.getFetches(), countRoot, copyContext);

        countQuery.select(cb.count(countRoot));
        countQuery.where(((SqmPredicate) criteria.getRestriction()).copy(copyContext));

        countRoot.alias(root.getAlias());

        return countQuery.distinct(criteria.isDistinct());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static void doJoinsOnFetches(Set<? extends Fetch<?, ?>> joins, Root<?> root, SqmCopyContext copyContext) {
        doJoins((Set<? extends Join<?, ?>>) joins, root, copyContext);
    }

    private static void doJoins(Set<? extends Join<?, ?>> joins, Root<?> root, SqmCopyContext copyContext) {
        for (Join<?, ?> join : joins) {
            Join<?, ?> joined = root.join(join.getAttribute().getName(), join.getJoinType());
            joined.alias(join.getAlias());
            copyContext.registerCopy(join, joined);
            doJoins(join.getJoins(), joined);
        }
    }

    private static void doJoins(Set<? extends Join<?, ?>> joins, Join<?, ?> root, SqmCopyContext copyContext) {
        for (Join<?, ?> join : joins) {
            Join<?, ?> joined = root.join(join.getAttribute().getName(), join.getJoinType());
            joined.alias(join.getAlias());
            copyContext.registerCopy(join, joined);
            doJoins(join.getJoins(), joined);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: I was trying throughout multiple comments to explain what the OP should do, but apparently didn't understand what I was suggesting, so here is the solution. I'll repeat myself. The expressions you use for a query (selection or predicate) have to use `From`/`Join` nodes that were created for that same query. It's not possible to refer to other nodes from a different query. I suggested to simply rebuild the query for the needs of counting, but the OP wanted to rather copy the existing query, so I explained which API to use for that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this solution https://www.manongdao.com/q-308133.html, I have created a dynamic count class like this:

```
public class JpaUtil {

    public static <E, D> long count(final EntityManager entityManager,
                                    final CriteriaBuilder cb,
                                    final CriteriaQuery<D> criteria,
                                    final Root<E> root) {
        CriteriaQuery<Long> query = createCountQuery(cb, criteria, root, root.getModel().getJavaType());
        return entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
    }

    private static <T, D> CriteriaQuery<Long> createCountQuery(final CriteriaBuilder cb,
                                                               final CriteriaQuery<D> criteria,
                                                               final Root<T> root,
                                                               final Class<T> entityClass) {

        final CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        final Root<T> countRoot = countQuery.from(entityClass);

        doJoins(root.getJoins(), countRoot);
        doJoinsOnFetches(root.getFetches(), countRoot);

        countQuery.select(cb.count(countRoot));
        countQuery.where(criteria.getRestriction());

        countRoot.alias(root.getAlias());

        return countQuery.distinct(criteria.isDistinct());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static void doJoinsOnFetches(Set<? extends Fetch<?, ?>> joins, Root<?> root) {
        doJoins((Set<? extends Join<?, ?>>) joins, root);
    }

    private static void doJoins(Set<? extends Join<?, ?>> joins, Root<?> root) {
        for (Join<?, ?> join : joins) {
            Join<?, ?> joined = root.join(join.getAttribute().getName(), join.getJoinType());
            joined.alias(join.getAlias());
            doJoins(join.getJoins(), joined);
        }
    }

    private static void doJoins(Set<? extends Join<?, ?>> joins, Join<?, ?> root) {
        for (Join<?, ?> join : joins) {
            Join<?, ?> joined = root.join(join.getAttribute().getName(), join.getJoinType());
            joined.alias(join.getAlias());
            doJoins(join.getJoins(), joined);
        }
    }
}
```

Calling this is fairly easy and reused predicates already computed for the result query, like this:

```
long count = JpaUtil.count(entityManager, criteriaBuilder, criteriaQuery, root);
```

The problem occurs in hibernate-core 6+ because of this line:

```
countQuery.where(criteria.getRestriction());
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution didn't work for me in the version 6.2.13.Final with Spring 3.1.5

With the solution mark as correct I am receiving org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not locate TableGroup

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I miss understand actually @Abned you solution works for me thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35248846)